# Postman Mock server route params

Tags: mocking, postman, routeparams, mockserver

there is a problem in using postman mock server. It does not respond to the requests that have route parameters. For example, My uri looks like this:

```
PUT : {{server_url}}/order/{id}
```

But when I call mock server in this way:

```
{{mock_server}}/order/{id}
```

or

```
{{mock_server}}/order/1 or any other examples
```

the mock server response is:

```
{
"error": {
    "name": "mockRequestNotFoundError",
    "message": "We were unable to find any matching requests for this method type and the mock path, '/fa/order/', in your collection."
}
```

}

Could any body help me?

Answer (score 4):

You can edit your saved example to be `PUT : {{server_url}}/order/1`

Then 
`PUT {{mock_server}}/order/1` or `PUT {{mock_server}}/order/5` or `PUT {{mock_server}}/order/<any number>` should work.